# Calculate percentage and level using two functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am try to show the level as a number, and a progress bar that shows from 0 - 99 of the current level.

I've found a math formula online for leveling which is:

```
constant * Math.sqrt(xp);
```

I want to make two functions, one to calculate the current level, and one to calculate the current percentage (to display the progress bar)

Here are both functions so far:

```
function calculateLevel(xp: number): number {
  return 3/2 * Math.sqrt(xp);
}
```

This is the function that I am having trouble with:

```
// should return 0-99 
function calculatePercentage(xp: number): number {
  let currentLevel = calculateLevel(xp);
  // 0 - 99
  // totalLevelXP = find total xp needed to move from this level to next level?
  // 
  // ((total xp needed for next level) - currentXP) - total xp needed for this level
  // example
  let percentage = Math.floor(50.85);
  return percentage;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "next level"? Is the level supposed to be a discrete integer or a floating point?

Comment: levels would be integers (but they are just calculated based on the math formula at the top of my post from the current xp). I'm trying to show the percentage from 0-99 between this level and next level based on the current xp.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using currentLevel parameter
i think it must be like that

```
let percentage = Math.floor(currentLevel);
```